# 'IndexError: list index out of range' during assignment

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

```
j = [['4', '5'], ['1', '1'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '1']] 
k = [['5', '2'], ['4', '2'], ['2', '4'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '3']]
t = []
indexPointer = 0

for coord in j:
    for number in coord:
        t[indexPointer][0] = number
        indexPointer += 1
indexPointer = 0
for coord in k:
    for number in coord:
        t[indexPointer][1] = number
        indexPointer += 1
print(t)
```

should output:

```
[[4,5],[5,2],[1,4],[1,2],[1,2],[5,4],[3,3],[4,3],[3,4],[1,3]]
```

instead i get:

```
t[indexPointer][0] = number
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I solve this? I've tried to find a way but without any luck.

**Edit:**
I didn't include all the code necessary. It has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't index into an empty list, since there's nothing there. You'll either have to append things to it, or prefill it with empty values, eg:

```
t = [None] * 10
```

But even this won't exactly work, since you expect `t` to be two dimensional. You may want to try making t a `defaultdict`, like so:

```
from collection import defaultdict
t = defaultdict(dict)
t[1][0] = 'a'
```

Comment: I updated the code. I was a bit unclear originally. Maybe you could help me based on the updated question?

Comment: The same thing applies. You can't index into an empty list. You have to either make it into a dictionary, which you can index into at will, or prefill it with empty data.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't ths be out of range?

Your `t` variable is just an empty single dimensional list which you're trying to access as if it were 2-dimensional.

I think your just trying to add everything that is in `j` to `t`? In which case you could just do something like this: `t = list(itertools.chain(*j))`

Edit: Just noticed each element is in it's own list: `t = [[x] for x in itertools.chain(*j)]`

Comment: I updated the code. I was a bit unclear originally. Maybe you could help me based on the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the code posted by Pythonista, but to adjust your code to make it work:

```
j = [['4', '5'], ['1', '1'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '1']] 
t = []

for coord in j:
    for number in coord:
        t.append([number])

print(t)
#[['4'], ['5'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['5'], ['3'], ['4'], ['3'], ['1']]
```

As you're looping through each element the `.append` list method is tacking on `[number]` to the end of your list `t`.

You can accomplish this same nested loop code using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
t = [[number] for coord in j for number in coord]
```

**Update:**

Since you've updated your question:

You should consider the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function in this situation.

```
t=list(itertools.chain(*zip(j,k)))
```

To update the code from above if you want to use a `for` loop, but here you can use the list `.extend` method:

```
j = [['4', '5'], ['1', '1'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '1']] 
k = [['5', '2'], ['4', '2'], ['2', '4'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '3']]
t = []

for coord in zip(j,k):
    t.extend(coord)

print(t)
#[['4'], ['5'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['5'], ['3'], ['4'], ['3'], ['1']]
```

And as a comprehension:

```
t=[i for coord in zip(j,k) for i in coord]
```

Comment: I updated the code. I was a bit unclear originally. Maybe you could help me based on the updated question?

Comment: @NickWright I've updated my answer based on your update